# Filter a smaller file using another huge file

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have a huge csv file with about 10^9 lines where each line has a pair of ids such as:

```
IDa,IDb
IDb,IDa
IDc,IDd
```

Call this file1.  I have another much smaller csv file with about 10^6 lines in the same format. Call this file2.

I want to simply find the lines in file2 which contain at least one ID that exists somewhere in file1.

Is there a fast way to do this?  I don't mind if it is in awk, python or perl.

Comment: How many different kinds of ids are there about in file1? 10^9? Your example has 3 lines and 3 different ids.

Comment: i think you should try to do maybe piece of code in one of technology, now you just asked about your whole ready to work program.

Comment: @JamesBrown About 10^9 sadly.

Comment: Probably in two phases then. For example using AWK read all ids from file2 into memory, match those ids against file1 and you have a list of ids to fetch from file2. That way no need to store 10^9 keys in memory but only 10^6.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order of the lines from file2?

Comment: @ysth No I do not.

Comment: More context may be useful, for example are the ids sequential? Are the two files already sorted, or can they actually be sorted? If that's the case there you can easily find on the net a python or perl implementation of a binary search. I've used it in perl with a 4 million record file and it handled 50.000 queries per second.

Comment: @ChatterOne Sadly neither presorted nor are the ids sequential.

Comment: Is there any other data than the ids, like real payload, the third field or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cat > file2 # make test file2
IDb,IDa
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];a[$2];next} ($1 in a&&++a[$1]==1){print $1} ($2 in a&&++a[$2]==1){print $2}' file2 file1 > file3
$ cat file3 # file2 ids in file1 put to file3
IDa
IDb
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($1 in a)||($2 in a){print $0}' file3 file2
IDb,IDa
```

Comment: The OP wants to print the lines from file2, not from file1. Printing the lines from file1 would be MUCH simpler! If you meant to use `file2` instead of `file1` as the argument for your 2nd script - it would only print the first line from file2 that matched a field from file1 so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Oops, `file2` definitely. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. It'll still fail when the same key value appears multiple times in file2 though. Try it with `IDb,IDx` added to the end of your current file2. The statements in your 2nd script are just much more complicated than they should be - instead of `($1 in a&&++a[$1]==1){print $0;next} ($2 in a&&++a[$2]==1){print $0}`, all you need is `($1 in a) || ($2 in a)`.

Comment: w00t?! Where did that come from. Thanks again. I really should stop doing these between jobs...

Comment: You're welcome and you don't need to write `{print $0}` - that's the default action when a condition is true. And if you'd like to see how to do the same approach without a temp file, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39372191/1745001 and imagine `inBothFiles[]` was named `a[]` :-).

Comment: :D Yeah, I was thinking trying to combine those two into one but since I made a comment in the question of a two-phased solution I had to stand by my words...

Comment: looks like the OP prefers to need a temp file so... good choice? ;-).

Comment: After all that fixin' there can't be (m)any errors left... :D

Answer (score 4):

I would actually use `sqlite` for something like that. You could create a new database from the same directory as two files with `sqlite3 test.sqlite` and then do something like that:

```
create table file1(id1, id2);
create table file2(id1, id2);
.separator ","
.import file1.csv file1
.import file2.csv file2
WITH all_ids AS (
    SELECT id1 FROM file1 UNION SELECT id2 FROM file1
)
SELECT * FROM file2 WHERE id1 IN all_ids OR id2 IN all_ids;
```

The advantage of using `sqlite` is that you can manage the memory more intelligently than a simple script that you could write in some scripting language.

Comment: Thank you. I have never used sqlite. Do I just add from sqlite3 import *  ?

Comment: `sqlite3` is a stand alone executable. You just execute it with `sqlite3 test.sqlite` and it will create a new database called `test.sqlite`. Then it will give you a prompt where you can type sql commands. In that prompt, just type the commands I gave above.

Comment: Ah yes. There is also a python sqlite module I think which might also work.

Comment: Yes there is python sqlite module, but there is no need to use python for something so simple like that.

Comment: `UNION ALL` will include duplicates from `id2` and in worst case doubles the amount of ids in `all_ids`.

Comment: @JamesBrown You are right. I changed it to `UNION`. Semantically it didn't matter though because `IN` doesn't care about duplicates, but yes, it is better to take care of duplicates with `UNION` here.

Comment: @eleanora, please check back after trying this solution. I'd like to know how long it took? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using these input files for testing:

```
$ cat file1
IDa,IDb
IDb,IDa
IDc,IDd

$ cat file2
IDd,IDw
IDx,IDc
IDy,IDz
```

If file1 can fit in memory:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];a[$2];next} ($1 in a) || ($2 in a)' file1 file2
IDd,IDw
IDx,IDc
```

If not but file2 can fit in memory:

```
$ awk -F, '
    ARGIND==2 {
        if ($1 in inBothFiles) {
            inBothFiles[$1] = 1
        }
        if ($2 in inBothFiles) {
            inBothFiles[$2] = 1
        }
        next
    }
    ARGIND==1 {
        inBothFiles[$1] = 0
        inBothFiles[$2] = 0
        next
    }
    ARGIND==3 {
        if (inBothFiles[$1] || inBothFiles[$2]) {
            print
        }
    }
' file2 file1 file2
IDd,IDw
IDx,IDc
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND - with other awks just add a `FNR==1{ARGIND++}` block at the start.

I have the `ARGIND==2` block (i.e. the part that processes the 2nd argument which in this case is the 10^9 `file1`) listed first for efficiency so we don't unnecessarily test `ARGIND==1` for every line in the much larger file.

Comment: file2 can fit in memory (but not file1)

Comment: OK, then the 2nd solution above will work for you. Enjoy... :-).

Answer (score 1):

In perl,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# read file2
open my $file2, '<', 'file2';
chomp( my @file2 = <$file2> );
close $file2;

# record file2 line numbers each id is found on
my %id;
for my $line_number (0..$#file2) {
    for my $id ( split /,/, $file2[$line_number] ) {
        push @{ $id{$id} }, $line_number;
    }
}

# look for those ids in file1
my @use_line;
open my $file1, '<', 'file1';
while ( my $line = <$file1> ) {
    chomp $line;
    for my $id ( split /,/, $line ) {
        if ( exists $id{$id} ) {
            @use_line[ @{ $id{$id} } ] = @{ $id{$id} };
        }
    }
}
close $file1;

# print lines whose ids were found
print "$_\n" for @file2[ grep defined, @use_line ];
```

Comment: This is Perl for anyone who hasn't worked it out ;-)

Comment: Curious to know how long this takes to run

Answer (score 0):

Sample files:

```
cat f1
IDa,IDb
IDb,IDa
IDc,IDd


cat f2
IDt,IDy
IDb,IDj
```

Awk solution:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1;b[$2]=$2;next} ($1 in a)||($2 in b)' f1 f2
IDb,IDj
```

This will store first and second columns of file1 in array a and b. Then print those line if either first or second column is seen for second file.

Comment: _which contain at least one ID that exists somewhere_ - wouldn't `a[]` be enough?

Comment: @JamesBrown , OP mentioned pair of ID's . So I am assuming both columns as IDs.

Comment: _I want to simply find the lines in file2 which contain ..._ - This solution returns lines from `file1`.

Comment: it looks to me like this needs to store in memory all the data from the bigger file (multiple gigabytes)

Comment: There are two ids per line.